# Using Google Knowledge Graph API to find relation between two nodes

Tags: google-knowledge-graph

Is it possible to query the Google Knowledge graph API to get an edge(or relation) between two nodes in it? Or alternatively, perhaps to find the nearest n nodes to a specified node?

Comment: Are you just asking for introductory computer discrete structures / algorithms help?

Comment: What I'm trying is to link entities in a sentence to a knowledge base and then leverage it to extract relations between them. I've already implemented this on NELL and Conceptnet KBs and was wondering if I could use Google KG API for the same.

Comment: @NaveenPratap: How did you implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Knowledge Graph API does not support relations between two entities (notice there is only one method `entities.search` available [here](https://developers.google.com/knowledge-graph/reference/rest/v1/)).

The closest you can get to comparing the two entities is by using Google Trends, e.g. for [`/m/0dl567` vs `/m/0478__m`](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?geo=US&q=%2Fm%2F0dl567,%2Fm%2F0478__m) (notice the Knowledge Graph IDs in the URL). As of August 2018, Google Trends does not offer an official API to do this programmatically.

To see the nearest nodes to a given node, you browse through the "Related topics" section in Google Trends, e.g. [here](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?geo=US&q=%2Fm%2F0dl567). The items in that list are URLs with IDs that you are looking for.